# Accessing HttpApplication.Application variables from a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, session-variables

I set up various global parameters in Global.asax, as such:

```
Application["PagePolicies"] = "~/Lab/Policies.aspx";
Application["PageShare"] = "/Share.aspx";
Application["FileSearchQueries"] = Server.MapPath("~/Resources/SearchQueries.xml");
...
```

I have no problem accessing these variables form .ascx.cs or .aspx.cs file -- ie. files that are part of the Web content. However, I can't seem to access 'Application' from basic class objects (ie. standalone .cs files). I read somewhere to use a slight variations in .cs files, as follows, but it always comes throws an exception when in use:

```
String file = (String)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["FileSearchQueries"];
```

Comment: Is your use from a non-aspx class within the context of Asp.Net?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it's true that you can use `HttpContext.Current` from any class you must still be processing an HTTP request when you call it - otherwise there is no current context. I presume that's the reason you're getting an exception, but posting the actual exception would help clarify matters.

Comment: I think you are correct... What's the best way to share variables then between all parts of my app? I only have a few minor irritants in .cs files that need a Web Content (such as Server.MapPath, above).

Comment: That's a whole separate question and you should probably post it separately with more details about the app and what you want to share.

Answer (score 4):

to share your variable across app, and to be able to access it from standalone class, you can use static variable of a class, instead of using HttpApplication variable.

```
public MyClass{
 public static int sharedVar;
}

//and than you can write somwhere in app:
MyClass.sharedVar= 1;

//and in another location:
int localVar = MyClass.sharedVar;
```

Comment: Of course, with the caveat that it should be a variable that other concurrent users of the system need as well. Static variables are shared across a multi-user environment. If the variable will be changed for user-specific reasons then this is not the approach you'll want to take. </ $0.02>